# arXiv trackbacks

Tags: discussion

I just noticed that [TP.SE now gets arXiv trackbacks](http://meta.theoreticalphysics.stackexchange.com/questions/227/arxiv-trackbacks-working).

Should we also ask for it? What do you think?

Comment: I think we should.

Comment: Could someone explain how these work, and what the purpose would be ?

Comment: @Suresh, it adds back-links from arXiv to the posts on TP.SE and MO. 

The purpose is: if someone is looking at a paper on arXiv they will see the links of cstheory question linking to it. One nice thing is that authors will see questions about their paper and the question may get an answer from the authors. :)

Comment: But I guess you already know [these](http://meta.theoreticalphysics.stackexchange.com/questions/55/integrating-arxiv-trackbacking-feature). :)

Comment: Clearly I'm getting forgetful in my old age

Answer (score 4):

I'm all for getting trackbacks. The more visibility the better. But how do we go about getting it ? Maybe ask @JoeFitzsimmons ?

Comment: I can send it if you like.

Comment: @PiotrMigdal that would be fantastic. Thanks !

Comment: Did you receive it? (I sent it a week ago.)